# How can I share my wired/wireless network with other devices on Kubuntu 13.10?

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager

How can I use new network manager applet to share my wired/wireless network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubuntu 13.10 has a new network manager applet. Here, sharing network using your wired or wireless network will be covered:

Click on network manager in system tray:

[image: Network manager icon]

Choose wrench icon (settings) and then click "Edit Connections":

[image: Choosing settings]

Connection Editor will be displayed. Click on Add then either Wireless (shared) or Wired (shared) depending on what you would like to share (here, a wired connection will be shared using wireless adapter):

[image: Shared network choices]

Enter a display name for your reference on computer and click on Wireless tab. Enter an SSID to be displayed in available networks list of your device and leave "Access Point" as mode:

[image: Entering basic info]

Lastly, choose "Wireless Security" tab and choose a security method (WPA & WPA2 Personal is recommended) and enter a password if you want to secure your network from other users.

[image: Choosing security method]

Click "OK" and you are done!

The next thing is just to connect your newly created network using your device:

[image: Android wireless list]